# Why is Kotlin with 50k iterations faster than Java?

Tags: java, android, performance, kotlin, compare

I have the same source code twice. Once in java and once in kotlin.

The algorithm is very simple.

First the java code:

```
public class ConcatString implements Runnable
{
private final int o;
long start;
private long conTime;


public ConcatString(final int o)
{
    this.o = o;
}

@Override
public void run()
{

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String s = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < o; i++)
    {
        s += i;
    }
    conTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
}

/**
 * @return the conTime
 */
public long getConTime()
{
    return conTime;
}
}
```

And here is the kotlin code:

```
class ConcatString(private val o: Int) : Runnable {
internal var start: Long = 0
/** @return the conTime
 */
var conTime: Long = 0


override fun run() {
    start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    var s = ""
    for (i in 0 until o) {
        s += i
    }
    // System.out.println(s);
    conTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
}
}
```

As you can see, it is easy! 
I compared these two by calculate the time. With 10k Java is faster than Kotlin, but with 50k times Kotlin is faster than Java.
I can't understand why this happen! 
Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: try with 100k times

Comment: First, use JMH for microbenchmarks like this -- the way you are doing it now is fraught with measurement error. Secondly, you can compare the bytecode to see any differences (use the bytecode viewer in IDEA). I think you'll find the Kotlin compiler optimizes the String concat to use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Your function(s) have no visible side effects; after some number of iteration tests the JIT is going to eliminate one (or both) loops.

Comment: This benchmark makes no sense, it basically exercises CPU's memcpy speed and generates huge GC pressure. Neither has a lot to do with the efficiency of the respective compilers. Apart from that, you have no warmup, you don't use the resulting string after the loop (so it's eligible for Dead Code Elimination), and many other problems.

Comment: Thanks for answers guys. Just for information, I never tried to benchmark my software before. Thats why I seems like a beginner code.